# How can I a closed form for this equation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have an equation as follows: $$[\gamma(\beta+y)+1]\exp(-(\beta+y)\gamma)>\{1-[\gamma(\beta+y)+1]\exp(-(\beta+y)\gamma)\}\alpha$$
where all parameters are positive.$$$$How can I a closed form for this equation( so as y> or < parameters of equation). I want to extract $y$ from inequality.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How can you *have a* closed form for this equation? :)

Comment: I need to have domain of y to solve my main problem!

Answer (score 2):

I do not see how to obtain a closed-form solution, but your inequality is clearly related to the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Let $w=-\gamma(\beta+y)-1$. Then
\begin{align}
[\gamma(\beta+y)+1]e^{-(\beta+y)\gamma} &>\{1-[\gamma(\beta+y)+1]e^{-(\beta+y)\gamma}\}\alpha,\\
-we^{1+w} &> \alpha[1+we^{1+w}],\\
-(\alpha+1)we^{1+w} &> \alpha,\\
we^w &< \frac{-\alpha/e}{\alpha+1}.
\end{align}
So, using notations from the Wikipedia page, we must have $W_{-1}\left(\frac{-\alpha/e}{\alpha+1}\right) < w < W_0\left(\frac{-\alpha/e}{\alpha+1}\right)$ (where $W_{-1}$ and $W_0$ are respectively the lower and upper branches of the double-valued Lambert $W$ function). To evaluate $W_{-1}\left(\frac{-\alpha/e}{\alpha+1}\right)$ and $W_0\left(\frac{-\alpha/e}{\alpha+1}\right)$ numerically, see the "[Numerical Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation)" and "[Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Software)" sections of the wiki page.